# Facebook private replies response doesn't give user_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I use the Private Replies API call to send a message in Messenger to someone commenting on a Facebook post. If [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/object/private_replies) says I should get back the message id and the user_id, I only get the message id in response:

> body:
>   '{"id":"m_ZpLkUdJGAoJ9WCpeROAvWJaHycesSPGVPmoNH0SXTUB8WYqRqHl0ru0y3mniMP3q7YL9rl1lfuQr0x9fyNP

Here is my API call code in ruby:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/" + @comment_id + "/private_replies?message=" + @trigger_message + "&access_token=" + @page_access_token
                  uri = URI.parse(url)
                  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
                  https.use_ssl = true
                  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
                  resp = https.request(request)
```

Why don't I get the user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook private replies API was supposed to return App scoped ID or ASID, though post the new app verification or around that time, they have stopped giving ASID into private reply API - most probably because they are heading towards returning Page scoped ID or PSID ([PSID Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/psid-api/faq/))

Though you can still get ASID from either :

a. The webhook that could be providing comment ID, it should be providing ASID as sender_id 
b. from field with parsing comment ID. This is used to parse single comment node, you can find more info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/)

Do keep in mind ASID to PSID migration...